# Converting UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am reading an XML document (UTF-8) and ultimately displaying the content on a Web page using ISO-8859-1. As expected, there are a few characters are not displayed correctly, such as `“`, `–` and `’` (they display as ?).

Is it possible to convert these characters from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1?

Here is a snippet of code I have written to attempt this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line);
}
br.close();

byte[] latin1 = sb.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");

return new String(latin1);
```

I'm not quite sure what's going awry, but I believe it's readLine() that's causing the grief (since the strings would be Java/UTF-16 encoded?). Another variation I tried was to replace latin1 with

```
byte[] latin1 = new String(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

I have read previous posts on the subject and I'm learning as I go. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a normalization routine in the standard library that will do this. I do not think conversion of "smart" quotes is handled by the standard [Unicode normalizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html) routines - but don't quote me.

The smart thing to do is to dump [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and start using `UTF-8`. That said, it is possible to encode any normally allowed Unicode code point into a HTML page encoded as `ISO-8859-1`. You can encode them using [escape sequences](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) as shown here:

```
public final class HtmlEncoder {
  private HtmlEncoder() {}

  public static <T extends Appendable> T escapeNonLatin(CharSequence sequence,
      T out) throws java.io.IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++) {
      char ch = sequence.charAt(i);
      if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(ch) == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN) {
        out.append(ch);
      } else {
        int codepoint = Character.codePointAt(sequence, i);
        // handle supplementary range chars
        i += Character.charCount(codepoint) - 1;
        // emit entity
        out.append("&#x");
        out.append(Integer.toHexString(codepoint));
        out.append(";");
      }
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
String foo = "This is Cyrillic Ya: \u044F\n"
    + "This is fraktur G: \uD835\uDD0A\n" + "This is a smart quote: \u201C";

StringBuilder sb = HtmlEncoder.escapeNonLatin(foo, new StringBuilder());
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Above, the character LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK ( `U+201C` **“** ) is encoded as &#x201C;. A couple of other arbitrary code points are likewise encoded.

Care needs to be taken with this approach. If your text needs to be escaped for HTML, that needs to be done before the above code or the ampersands end up being escaped.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: This just saved me a lot of grief!

Comment: please have a look at my comment under @robinst answer

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your default encoding, following lines could cause problem,

```
byte[] latin1 = sb.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");

return new String(latin1);
```

In Java, String/Char is always in UTF-16BE. Different encoding is only involved when you convert the characters to bytes. Say your default encoding is UTF-8, the `latin1` buffer is treated as UTF-8 and some sequence of Latin-1 may form invalid UTF-8 sequence and you will get ?.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8, [McDowell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274830/305973) can be simplified like this (while preserving correct handling of surrogate pairs):

```
public final class HtmlEncoder {
    private HtmlEncoder() {
    }

    public static <T extends Appendable> T escapeNonLatin(CharSequence sequence,
                                                          T out) throws java.io.IOException {
        for (PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iterator = sequence.codePoints().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            int codePoint = iterator.nextInt();
            if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(codePoint) == Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN) {
                out.append((char) codePoint);
            } else {
                out.append("&#x");
                out.append(Integer.toHexString(codePoint));
                out.append(";");
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, if this is a correct check for Latin-1(ISO-8859-1) symbols. I am using instead as a check ``Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder().canEncode((char) codePoint)``, of course ``Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder()`` to be kept as a constant or method variable.

Answer (score 1):

when you instanciate your String object, you need to indicate which encoding to use.

So replace :

```
return new String(latin1);
```

by

```
return new String(latin1, "ISO-8859-1");
```