# nolatin characters in xml output

Tags: xml, utf-8

Edit: I hardcoded the charcter and use repsonse writer to write it, it still comes out to be 
K�nigsberger

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            response.setContentType(contentType);
            //if(contentType!=null)response.setHeader("Content-Type",contentType);
            Writer writer = response.getWriter();//new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8");
            System.err.println("character encoding is "+response.getCharacterEncoding());


            writer.write("Königsberger ");
            writer.flush();
```

Edit:
I tried setContentType and setContentEncoding prior to calling getWriter(), still no difference in output:

```
        if(res.length()>0){
            //pw.write(res);
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setContentType(contentType);
            //if(contentType!=null)response.setHeader("Content-Type",contentType);
            Writer writer = response.getWriter();//new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8");
            System.err.println("character encoding is "+response.getCharacterEncoding());


            writer.write(res);
            writer.flush();
        }
```

I am reading some german characters then output them in xml from java servlet,
here's how I read them in UTF8:

```
int len=0;
        byte[]buffer=new byte[1024];
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        query += "\r\n";
        os.write(query.getBytes("UTF8"));//iso8859_1"));

            do{
                len = is.read(buffer);
             if (len>0) { 
                 if(outstring==null)outstring=new StringBuffer();
                 outstring.append(new String(buffer,0,len, "UTF8"));
             }
           }while(len>0);
System.out.println(outstring);
```

System.out outputs the string correctly:
Königsberger

However when I repipe this string from my servletResponse also using charset=UTF-8
it becomes gobbled: K�nigsberger

```
private void outputResponse(String res, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String outputFormat = getOutputFormat(request);
        String contentType=null;
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        //response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        System.err.println("output "+res);

        contentType= "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
        res="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + res;

        if(contentType!=null)response.setHeader("Content-Type",contentType);
        if(res.length()>0){
            pw.write(res);
        }
        pw.flush();

    }
```

Comment: specify OS/platform. what is and how do you "repipe"?

Comment: os is window. by repipe I simply mean outputing it from Servlet

Answer (score 3):

```
do{
  len = is.read(buffer);
  if (len>0) { 
    if(outstring==null) outstring=new StringBuffer();
    outstring.append(new String(buffer,0,len, "UTF8"));
  }
}while(len>0);
```

This is not a good way to decode UTF-8 as characters can become corrupted on buffer boundaries ([details here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_stringclass)). UTF-8 is a *variable width encoding*, so characters require between one and four bytes to store. If it is working, you are just getting lucky. It is better to encode and decode using the Reader/Writer classes ([details here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_streams)).

I believe you need to call either [setContentType](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)) or [setCharacterEncoding](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String)) prior to calling `getWriter`. I don't think it is enough to call `setHeader` directly.

---

This servlet code will correctly encode and transmit the sample string as UTF-8 data:

```
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    pw.write("<data>K\u00F6nigsberger</data>");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
  }
```

Note that I am using the escape sequence `\u00F6` to emit the character U+00F6 (**ö**) to ensure that I do not corrupt the character in my text editor or during the compilation process ([see here for more details](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles)).

Is it possible that the data is being misinterpreted on the client? Check the output with a hex editor.

Encoded as UTF-8, `"K\u00F6nigsberger"` should become the byte sequence:

```
4b c3 b6 6e 69 67 73 62 65 72 67 65 72
```

...where the character U+00F6 (**ö**) becomes `c3 b6`. You can use code like this to check your values:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String konigsberger = "K\u00F6nigsberger";
    dumpHex(System.out, konigsberger.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  }

  private static void dumpHex(PrintStream out, byte[] data) {
    for (byte b : data) {
      out.format("%02x ", b);
    }
    out.println();
  }
```

Comment: I suspect it's an xml formatting issue rather than unicode encoding.
I used the code  pw.write("<data>K\u00F6nigsberger</data>"); and when I view it in browser the character still gets corrupted...

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the example and make servlet `response` understand which endcoding to follow:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
ServletOutputStream out =response.getOutputStream();
out.write(output.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You allways can use entities like this:

```
<test>
&#228;
&#252;
&#229;
</test>
```

to get:

```
<test>
ä
ü
å
</test>
```

Maybe not exactly what you want, but a nice workaround. You can use sites like [utf8-chartable.de](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) to look up the needed value.

Comment: this outputs the de characters fine, is there a way to convert these de characters into these xml codes?

Comment: I mean is there a java api to do the conversion directly in java?

Comment: @unknown (google): There is no Java API that will create these entities automagically. See this answer for an example of how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273986/converting-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-in-java/1274830#1274830

Comment: I'm not sure, if there is a library. What about commons lang StringEscapeUtils. There is a escapeXml Method, that looks promising: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I have just done the following things and it is working fine:

```
byte[] k =xml.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET); // xml is the string with unicode content.  getBytes("UTF-16") encodes given String into a sequence of bytes and returns an array of bytes. you can use xml.getBytes(UTF-16); for utf-16 encoding

response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setContentLength(k.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(k);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```