# How To HTML Escape Curly Quotes in a Java String

Tags: java, unicode, html-entities

I've got a string that has curly quotes in it. I'd like to replace those with HTML entities to make sure they don't confuse other downstream systems. For my first attempt, I just added matching for the characters I wanted to replace, entering them directly in my code:

```
public static String escapeXml(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char characters[] = s.toCharArray();
    for ( int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++ ) {
        char c = characters[i];
        switch (c) {
            // other escape characters deleted for clarity
            case '“':
                sb.append("&#8220;");
                break;
            case '”':
                sb.append("&#8221;");
                break;
            case '‘':
                sb.append("&#8216;");
                break;
            case '’':
                sb.append("&#8217;");
                break;
            default:
                sb.append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This compiled and worked fine on my Mac, but when our CI server (which runs on Linux) tried to build it, it choked:

```
Out.java:[347,16] duplicate case label
```

Apparently some part of the build chain on the Linux box can't recognize and distinguish among these fancy characters.

My next attempt was to use Unicode escaping. Unfortunately, this won't even compile on my Mac:

```
...
            case '\u8220':
                sb.append("&#8220;");
                break;
            case '/u8221':
                sb.append("&#8221;");
                break;
...
```

My compiler throws this complaint:

```
Out.java:[346,21] unclosed character literal
```

I'm baffled as to how one might do this bit of substitution and have it work reliably across platforms. Does anybody have any pointers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about not using curly quotes?

Comment: ...wait, is that supposed to be `case '/u8221':` or `case '\u8221':`?

Comment: Re: Unicode escaping - I see that the 2 switch cases have different slashes - \ and /

Comment: @Matt: the data comes from our CMS, where the marketing folks put in whatever crazy stuff they want. :)

Comment: @Sean McMains - see this answer for how to escape any Unicode codepoint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273986/converting-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-in-java/1274830#1274830

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler problem is because you've got '/u8221' instead of '\u8221' - a forward slash instead of a backslash.

I'm not entirely convinced that using the entities will help, but you can try... I suppose it depends on how broken the downstream code is.

EDIT: Doh, I hadn't spotted that your Unicode values were in decimal. Yes, they need to be in hex :) I'll leave this answer here as it explains why the compiler was complaining - '\u8221' is a perfectly character escape sequence, just not the one you wanted :)

Comment: That would have been another case of “Why do Chinese character show up in the middle of my English text?” ;-)

Comment: Hah! Well, that was definitely my first problem. Kicking myself for that one -- thanks, Jon.

Answer (score 4):

Unicode literals are in hexadecimal:

```
case '\u201c':
    sb.append("&#8220;");
    break;
....
```

And, as mentioned in the other answers, you've got a `/` instead of a `\` in one of your literals.

Comment: And this was my second issue. Appreciate it, Adam.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the literal character (i.e., `'‘'`), but your build process needs to specify the correct source encoding during compilation. The `javac` command option is `-encoding`. (The attribute on Ant's `javac` task is the same.) This should match whatever encoding used by your IDE when saving the files.

If your IDE is using UTF-8, for example, but the build machine is using its platform default encoding of US-ASCII, the special characters will be decoded as `?`. Since multiple cases now have the same label, you get the original error message.

Comment: This is very good to know. I think I'm going to keep going with the escaped version, however, so that we don't have to fight with encoding issues across various machines when we check out our code. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding varies from platform to platform - Windows uses its own ISO-Latin-1 dialect (at least those I've worked on).  Linux frequently use UTF-8 (which is most likely your problem) and Mac uses MacRoman.  You can circumvent most of your problems by keeping to plain 7-bit ASCII, and using \u for anything above that if you need it in your source code.

Personally I would keep anything "national" outside the Java source, and use the Localization features to look up translated strings for simple keys and *they* are placed in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use Apache Commons Lang http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html.

Comment: I actually like this library a lot, but it wasn't escaping exactly what we needed, so we had to do our custom version. (Old versions of IE gave us trouble with apostrophes encoded their way, as I recall.)