# application configuration file in C# question

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xpath, selenium, app-config

I am using selenium with c# to write automated tests for a website. I am still learning selenium and c#, and getting into issues here and there. I am not sure what would be a good approach. Would app.config file in c# be a good idea to store all xpaths of objects in the website? Or is it not a good idea to store hundreds of these object definitions in an xml file like app.config. Also, right now, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Machine" value="localhost"/>
  </appSettings>
 </configuration>
```

and, I am using a method in my class to get the values from this app.config file:

```
    public string GetAppConfig(string key)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].ToString();
    }
```

Is this a good way to retrieve values from app.config. Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help. I am really confused to as what I should be doing to store xpaths. I do not want to do something like:

```
Selenium.Click(\\id="...."\)
```

because that would be difficult to change if the xpaths change in the website later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in `ConfigurationManager` where possible, avoid rolling your own if you don't need to. You can make this helper class static so it can be called direct without creating a new instance.

Note that in your code, if the key doesn't exist it will throw an exception, depending on your requirements you may want to catch it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the config file for this, but would have to deal with unessessary xml.

Personally I would just write a simple file parser that reads key=property (line by line):

[Can .NET load and parse a properties file equivalent to Java Properties class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485659/can-net-load-and-parse-a-properties-file-equivalent-to-java-properties-class)