# Update web.config applicationSettings programmatically with C# (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, web-config

I want to update web reference Url in web.config applicationSettings at runtime

Here is web config application settings

```
<applicationSettings>
<ItineraryBuilder.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="ItineraryBuilder_SchedulesConnectionsService_SchedulesConnectionsService"
    serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://www.pathfinder-xml.com/soap/*/services/SchedulesConnections</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="ItineraryBuilder_SalesForceService_SforceService"
    serializeAs="String">
    <value>https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/25.0/0DFd00000000Wa6</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="ItineraryBuilder_OAGService_CBWSPublicService"
    serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://ondemand.oag.com:80/CBWebServicePublic/CBWSPubliclPort</value>
  </setting>
</ItineraryBuilder.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

here is my code using to update

```
var configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = (System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection)configuration.GetSection("applicationSettings/ItineraryBuilder.Properties.Settings");

System.Configuration.SettingValueElement sv = new System.Configuration.SettingValueElement();
sv.Equals("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/25.0/0DFd00000000Wa6");
section.Settings.Get("ItineraryBuilder_SalesForceService_SforceService").Value = sv;
configuration.Save();
```

But it does not update Value, instead remove Value tag from settings

Earlier i was trying to update Web service url, but did not work so i follow this approach, will you please guide me on how to update web service url?

this is what i was doing

```
SforceService sf = new SforceService();
sf.Url = "test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/25.0/0DFd00000000Wa6";;
```

Please help.

Comment: sv is empty. This line `sv.Equals("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/25.0/0DFd00000000Wa6");` doesn't do anything.

Comment: so will you please tell me how to set it? i tired this section.Settings.Get("ItineraryBuilder_SalesForceService_SforceService").Value.ValueXml.InnerText = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/25.0/0DFd00000000Wa6"; did not work either

Comment: @tomfanning is right. Don't do this, but when you want to invoke the web service change the url of the instance.

Comment: i was trying that too , but did not work so is follow this approach, will you please guide me on how to update web service url? this is what i was doing  SforceService sf = new SforceService();
            sf.Url = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/25.0/0DFd00000000Wa6";

Comment: Edit your question with this code also.

Comment: Question has been edited, please advice

Comment: How did you notice it didn't work?

Comment: i have two API Salesforce Production and Sandbox, and diff credentials, then i set Web-reference Production url but credential of Sandbox, then change Url to Sandbox in code but it still gives Invalid Login error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16019/discussion-between-anil-d-and-amiram-korach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Amiram Korach for all you help

With his help i got what i was doing wrong.

As he suggested there is no need to update web config as it is not a good approach and so the solution for the above problem is updating Web reference at runtime and so the following code works fine

```
SforceService sf = new SforceService();
sf.Url = "test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/25.0/0DFd00000000Wa6"
```

what i was doing wrong, the "sf" was not passed to API class which is used in creating connection.  Amiram Korach helped me finding this issue.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.

Specifically, one would hope that your web application root folder isn't writeable by the application pool identity.