# How to extract string from java properties

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the java properties content

```
xxx_error_tx1 = This is xxxx. Johe say:
xxx_error_MapCode = xxx_error_tx1, test this function,Failed,\
               Default, Current,\
               App_Error_tx1
```

I need to extract string ID and string content, I can extract line1 content correctly, but the second line content extract only the first string `xxx_error_tx1, test this function,Failed,\`. The rest of string cannot extract.

The regex string is `(?<ID>.+?)=(?<Translation>.+?)$`, I know this regex have some problem, but I've tried to modify to correct pattern but maybe I am newbie, the result still cannot meet my request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can .NET load and parse a properties file equivalent to Java Properties class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485659/can-net-load-and-parse-a-properties-file-equivalent-to-java-properties-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
(?<ID>.+?)=(?<Translation>(?:(?!\S+\s*=)[\s\S])+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC0qA9/2)

`(?:(?!\S+\s*=)[\s\S])+` Matches one or more space or non-space characters which won't contain the string which was matched by this `\S+\s*=` pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I have other question, if the next line is a comment line

xxx_error_MapCode = xxx_error_tx1, test this function,Failed,\
               Default, Current,\
               App_Error_tx1
# Reports

The result will include the comment line, may I can use [^#] to ignore the comment line, but I don't know should I insert to which position.

Comment: Yes, very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it correctly include the whole value when the value is splited on multiple lines but stop before line that follow.

```
(?<ID>.+?)=(?<Translation>(?:.*\\\s)*.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jP6jB7/1)